# No matching distribution found when installing from local python index

Tags: python-3.x, pypi

I'm trying to install packages from local package index. I have a package named **scikit_image-0.14.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64**. In pip requirements file the package is defined as **scikit-image==0.14.0**. When i try to run

```
pip install --index my_url requirements.cfg
```

I get Error: "No matching distribution found for pip_requirements.cfg".

When i install from PyPI all works well. Am I missing something?

Comment: `pip install --index my_url -r requirements.cfg`?

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The command you posted is trying to install the `requirements.cfg` project, which doesn't exist. Perhaps you mean:

```
$ pip install --index my_url -r requirements.cfg
```

to install from a requirements file called `requirements.cfg`?